# Discriminant of $x^2+x-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working on a homework problem, and am worried I'm going crazy. I believe $x^2+x-1$ is irreducible, but it's discriminant is $1^2-4(1)(-1)=5$ is positive, which would make it reducible (since quadratic $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ is irreducible $\leftrightarrow(b^2-4c)<0$). Am I missing something here?

Comment: reducible over the real numbers, not the rationals

Comment: Note this is the familiar golden ratio quadratic, reflected about the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we ask about irreducibility, we do so with respect to a given field.  Over certain fields, a polynomial might be irreducible, whereas it might not be over others.

Since $f(x) = x^2 + x - 1$ has degree $\leq 3$, it suffices to determine whether roots exist in the specified field.  That is, if $\deg(f) \leq 3$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F \iff$ $f$ has a root $\alpha \in F$.  Of course, it's a worthwhile exercise for you to prove this.

So now, this boils down to choosing our field.  Is $f$ reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?  Certainly not.  One can use the rational roots theorem, reduce $\pmod{2}$, or any of your favorite methods to show this.

Is it reducible over $\mathbb{R}$?  Certainly!  You even did all the work for yourself: since $\Delta \geq 0$, the quadratic formula guarantees roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Side note: The *only* irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ are quadratics with negative discriminant.  It might also be a worthwhile exercise to prove this.

Comment: Wow, that's an old post.  Thanks for that catch @SpamIAm!!

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{R}[x]$, it is reducible because
$$x^2+x-1=\left[x-\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}\right]\left[x-\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}\right].$$
It is not reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ because you cannot rewrite it into the form $(x+a)(x+b)$ where $a,b$ are rationals.